# Why doesn't Silverlight support Cursors.SizeAll?

Tags: silverlight, cursor

**Cursors.SizeAll** is one of a few Windows cursors that are apparently off-limits for Silverlight.  What is the reason for this?

I read [somewhere](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-TW/1511/thread/b9cabd98-4c8f-4cd3-b1ca-4f49dd586369) (not English) that it was done to reduce the size of the runtime.  Is that true?

Comment: In what situation would you use such a cursor?

Comment: I'd use it for resizing elements.  The diagonal resizing cursors would be great too.  I've seen examples where people had to use SizeNS or SizeWE when a person manipulated one of the corner resize handles of an object.  Just feels cheesey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of question is difficult to answer since the only people who can authoritatively answer it are the Silverlight team.  There are quite a few missing so it would seem Silverlight has had to make some kind of choice as to which ones are the most commonly used.  There is probably some cross platform considerations as well.  Do UIs on a Mac use the SizeAll cursor, I dunno.

I can't think of where I would use the SizeAll cursor.

Comment: Yes, my hunch is that it was a cross platform thing rather than trying to reduce the size of the runtime, but there's gotta be someone out there who knows the the answer.

Comment: The chaps at MS do lurk about in the Silverlight tag, however even they may need to dig into meeting minutes of yore to discover the real reason.  It doesn't seem to be that significant a choice that someone would simply remember the reason.

Comment: Maybe so.  But if it's a cross-platform thing, I shouldn't hold my breath for them adding it back in.  If it's a runtime size issue, they may add it in the future.